# Tika 1.14: getting java.lang.NullPointerException for PDFTextStripper

Tags: java, eclipse, pdfbox, apache-tika

I'm getting the following error message when parsing a PDF file with Apache Tika's PDFParser

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:150)
    at tikapdf.TikaPdfParser.main(TikaPdfParser.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.<clinit>(PDFTextStripper.java:1852)
    ... 2 more
```

I get the error **before** and **after** adding PDFBox jars. Tika 1.14 is supposed to be bundled already with PDFBox. Below the Eclipse IDE screen showing all information and the Java code.

```
package tikapdf;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class TikaPdfParser {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
        try {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Users\\bguarism\\workspace\\NLP\\invoice89526610.pdf"));

            BodyContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler(-1); //-1 to allow parsing for unlimited character          
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            ParseContext context = new ParseContext();          

            //parsing the document using PDF parser
            PDFParser parser = new PDFParser();         
            parser.parse(input, textHandler, metadata, context);

            System.out.println("Title: "+ metadata.get(Metadata.TITLE));
            //System.out.println("Body: "+ textHandler.toString());

            input.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

[image: Eclipse IDE view of code, libraries, and console]

Comment: That code line is searching for the resource "org/apache/pdfbox/resources/text/BidiMirroring.txt". It would be interesting to find out whether it is in tika app. Have you checked the size and/or the checksum?

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. I've only downloaded JAR files. Now, after downloading `pdfbox-2.0.4-src` (source) I've found the `BidiMirroring.txt` file within `pdfbox-2.0.4\pdfbox\src\main\resources\org\apache\pdfbox\resources` folder. What is the easiest way to make it work with my Tika code ?

Comment: It should also be in the tika app jar. From my understanding you don't need the pdfbox files because these are part of tika. That why I asked "Have you checked the size and/or the checksum?".

Comment: MD5 signature matched ! no problem there.

Comment: I looked at the tika jar, the file is there in org\apache\pdfbox\resources\text\ . So I'd suspect some eclipse problem. I can't help there because I use netbeans.

Comment: I've learnt something: I can explore the content of a JAR file with 7-zip, cool. I also confirm that BidiMirroring.txt is in the downloaded tika app JAR file (org\apache\pdfbox\resources\text\). Now, how can I be sure it's a Eclipse problem ?

Comment: Nothing is sure in life. But I doubt that tika would be unable to do something as simple as your code. Thus I'm betting on a configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is older, but I have run into the same issue today in combination with Eclipse Neon.

So here goes a possible explanation for your issue.

- PDFbox has some class initializers that are using the logic "<Class>.class.getClassLoader()" to get an instance of the class loader that is being associated with the class. I expect that line 1852 of your PDFTextStripper.java file being used as source for the version you have been using will contain a reference to this call.
- If you decide to mark your Eclipse libraries as "system libraries" then getClassLoader will return "null" as they are being mounted into the bootstrap loader, therefore you are getting a NullPointerException. The subsequent getResourceAsStream call is being tried against a null value and therefore it fails, obviously.
- This also will be applicable for Apache XML-Beans 2.6, or Apache POI and other implementations.

Possible easy resolution: remove the flag "system library" from the Eclipse library definitions and getClassLoader will return an instance to the class loader. Thus you won't run into the exception anymore.

Harder resolution: patch the code base for PDFBox and check for null value. If applicable use ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() instaead. Re-compile with Maven.